# find a element in a vector from one of its arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

How would i find a element in a vector from one of its arguments set with emplace_back
Trying to detach thread then delete it from vector.

```
std::vector<std::thread> vTimerThreads;
void SetTimer(UINT ID, DWORD dwMilliseconds)
{
    // timerThreadProc is my thread that handles my timers
    vTimerThreads.emplace_back(timerThreadProc, ID, dwMilliseconds);
}
void DeleteTimer(UINT ID)
{
    //Find thread by ID?
    //  thread.detach();
    // then delete
}

SetTimer(TIMER1, 5000);
```

Comment: You haven't stored `ID` anywhere, at least anywhere accessible from the vector.

Answer (score 3):

[std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) sounds like what you want if you're just going to remove based on id.

```
void DeleteTimer(std::thread::id ID)
{
    std::vector<std::thread>::iterator itr = std::find_if(vTimerThreads.begin(), vTimerThreads.end(), [&](const std::thread& t) { return t.get_id() == ID; });
    if( itr != vTimerThreads.end() )
       vTimerThreads.erase(itr);
}
```

I've used a lambda here but it's not necessary.

If you're thinking of using a large number of threads, maybe a different data structure would suit you better. Have you considered an std::set for faster searching? Perhaps even a map or hash_map would be good for you, where the id is the key? You could put the threads into these containers with move semantics instead of emplace_back without having copying (as I suspect is motivating you to use emplace).

Check out the [std::algorithm library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) though, there's some great stuff in there

EDIT:
I see in one of the comments OP says that ID is not in fact the thread id. Unless we can get clarification on what member of T for `std::vector<T>` we are meant to be searching on, an explicit solution cannot be provided.

As long as I'm doing an edit, here's some code for adding threads to a std::map without copying. With the following code it'll be trivial to find an element by std::thread::id or whatever else you want to use as a key and then delete it.

```
std::map<std::thread::id, std::thread> mapTimerThreads;

void AddNewThreadToMap()
{
    std::thread t;
    mapTimerThreads[t.get_id()] = std::move(t);
}
```

Comment: You should check `itr != vTimerThreads.end()` before erase it.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh gosh, I can't believe I left that out. Thank you for catching that! I've edited the answer with that addition.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a simple linear search (which makes sense if the number of threads is not large) you can just do

```
void DeleteTimer(UINT ID)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < vTimerThreads.size(); i++)
    if(vTimerThreads[i].get_id() == ID)
    {
      vTimerThreads.erase(vTimerThreads.begin()+i);
      break;
    }
}
```

If your number of threads is large, arbitrary deletion like this is expensive - you might want to consider something like `forward_list` instead of `vector` in that case.

Comment: You've just re-implemented `std::find_if`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know about that function. Thanks for the tip. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @ramafe "If the thread object is joinable, the function returns a value that uniquely identifies the thread." From cplusplus.com. So if the thread object is joinable, will you not get the thread ID?

Comment: @chris Actually, in this case, it's not so easy to use find_if. I looked it up - you need to specify a comparison function. It's not obvious to me how to write such a function in this case.

Comment: @AdityaKashi, `[](const auto& thr) { return thr.get_id() == ID; }`. Once the algorithms get updated with the Ranges TS, you should be able to do `std::find(begin, end, ID, &std::thread::get_id)` for the same effect (although it would *technically* not be guaranteed to compile given a weird implementation).